Is it acceptable to respond to a reviewer by indicating that their request is practically unfeasible, while providing valid justifications?
I am currently addressing feedback from a reviewer regarding my paper, in which the reviewer recommends comparing my results with those of other similar studies. However, such comparisons are not feasible because, although the suggested studies bear some resemblance to my work, they differ in key aspects that preclude direct comparison. Would it be appropriate to communicate this concern to the reviewer, supported by valid justifications, or might this approach lead to negative perceptions on their part?

"Infeasible" to me means something like "that would cost a million dollars and take four years," not "these studies are different in key aspects." It sounds like you should explain what the differences are, what comparisons aren't possible, and what are.

@Azor Ahai -him, In a straightforward manner, the studies proposed by the reviewer address discrete values, whereas my research focuses on continuous variables. Consequently, a direct comparison of the results from these two types of analyses is not feasible due to their inherent methodological differences.

Not necessarily. You can definitely compare a study of people with ADHD to those without and a study of people where ADHD was measured dimensionally. This sounds like a time to deepen your understanding of the field. As a reviewer, I would not be impressed with a claim that "comparing these studies is infeasible because one is continuous and the other is discrete."

@Azor Ahai -him, The distinctions between continuous and discrete values significantly influence the outcomes of both studies, rendering direct comparisons problematic. This fundamental difference in data type and analysis methodology creates a scenario akin to comparing apples and oranges, as the underlying assumptions, statistical treatments, and interpretations of results differ markedly between the two approaches. Thus, any attempt to juxtapose the findings of these studies would not yield meaningful insights.

Did the reviewer say "directly compare"? You have inserted the word "direct" here. Did you ask ChatGPT for help with that comment?

Yes I did. The reviewer did not ask me to "directly compare" the results of both studies. However, I am not sure that explaining the whole situation here to the reviewer can result in a bad interpretation for him about the paper or not.

Not particularly interested in talking to ChatGPT. See ya.

"although the suggested studies bear some resemblance to my work, they differ in key aspects" This does sound like a comparison of the studies.

I assume you're using ChatGPT because you're not confident in your English language skills. Unfortunately using ChatGPT is likely to make up and add new details to your writing which confuses you and everyone else. Don't ever use ChatGPT when you are unable to personally verify the output in detail. It's rude to waste other people's time with ChatGPT hallucinations.

What you wrote is already a comparison. You could add a couple of sentences to your paper explaining why other studies are different and preclude direct comparison. If you think these previous works are relevant, they could be cited in this way.

If you feel that you cannot or should not make changes to respond to these comments then you need to explain why, more for the editor than the specific reviewer. It might be a judgement call in the eyes of the editor and it could go either way.
I can't predict the outcome and it could be anywhere from acceptance of your argument to rejection of the paper. But, yes, it is appropriate and necessary to respond in some way to reviewer comments even if you don't change the paper. Don't just ignore the comment, even if you think it misplaced.
